# Scaling with touchesMoved:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, touchesmoved, uibezierpath

I have a [pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfZO1.png) which is made using UIBezierPath's. I now need those individual paths (pie pieces) to be scalable. I believe you need a view to be able to use pinch scaling, so I think touchesMoved: is the way to go (unless there's a workaround).

Any advice or help is appreciated!

**Updated/Progress code**

MySliceClass.m

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)sliceRadius:(float)radius andStartingAngle:(float)startingAngle andFinishingAngle:(float)finishingAngle
{
  static UIBezierPath *path = nil;
  path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
  CGPoint center = {300,300};
  [path moveToPoint:center];
  [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:radians(startingAngle) endAngle:radians(finishingAngle) clockwise:YES];
  [path closePath];
  path.lineWidth = 1;

  [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
  [path fill];

  return path;
}
```

MySliceView.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
  NSArray *arrayOfSlices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            slice01 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:0.5 andFinishingAngle:29.5],
                            slice02 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:30.5 andFinishingAngle:59.5],
                            slice03 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:60.5 andFinishingAngle:89.5],
                            slice04 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:90.5 andFinishingAngle:119.5],
                            slice05 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:120.5 andFinishingAngle:149.5],
                            slice06 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:150.5 andFinishingAngle:179.5],
                            slice07 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:180.5 andFinishingAngle:209.5],
                            slice08 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:210.5 andFinishingAngle:239.5],
                            slice09 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:240.5 andFinishingAngle:269.5],
                            slice10 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:270.5 andFinishingAngle:299.5],
                            slice11 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:300.5 andFinishingAngle:329.5],
                            slice12 = [WordplaySlice sliceRadius:200 andStartingAngle:330.5 andFinishingAngle:359.5], nil];                             
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find it easier if you create a view for each slice, and use a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`.  Here's how.

First, we need a `UIView` subclass that draws one slice.  It should also override `pointInside:withEvent:` to ignore a touch that lands outside the slice (even if the touch is inside the view's rectangular bounds).

So we'll make a class called `SliceView`.  It uses `CAShapeLayer` to do the slice drawing:

```
@interface SliceView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat padding;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat startRadians;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat endRadians;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *fillColor;

@end

@implementation SliceView

@synthesize padding = _padding;
@synthesize startRadians = _startRadians;
@synthesize endRadians = _endRadians;
@synthesize fillColor = _fillColor;
```

We tell it to use a `CAShapeLayer` instead of a plain `CALayer` by overriding the `layerClass` method.  We'll also add a handy method that returns the view's layer as a `CAShapeLayer`.

```
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)shapeLayer {
    return (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;
}
```

We'll compute the path of the slice in `layoutSubviews`, because the view receives the `layoutSubviews` message any time its size is changed.

We're going to lay out each slice view to cover the entire pie, but only draw its wedge of the pie.  Each slice's frame will cover the entire screen (if the pie is full-screen).  That means the slice view knows that the center of its arc is at the center of its bounds.  But then we use a little trigonometry to put in the padding between adjacent slices.

We also adjust the anchor point of the layer; this is the point in the layer that doesn't move when you scale or rotate the layer.  We want the anchor point to be at the corner of the slice nearest the center.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    CAShapeLayer *layer = self.shapeLayer;
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    CGFloat radius = MIN(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2 - 2 * _padding;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
    CGFloat sine = sinf((_startRadians + _endRadians) * 0.5f);
    CGFloat cosine = cosf((_startRadians + _endRadians) * 0.5f);
    center.x += _padding * cosine;
    center.y += _padding * sine;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:center];
    [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:_startRadians endAngle:_endRadians clockwise:YES];
    [path closePath];
    layer.path = path.CGPath;

    // Move my anchor point to the corner of my path so scaling will leave the corner in the same place.
    CGPoint cornerInSuperview = [self convertPoint:center toView:self.superview];
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(center.x / bounds.size.width, center.y / bounds.size.height);
    self.center = cornerInSuperview;
}
```

When any of the view's properties relating to the slice are changed, we need to recompute the path outlining the slice.  And when the fill color of the slice is changed, we need to pass that change along to the layer.  So we'll override the property setters.

```
- (void)setPadding:(CGFloat)padding {
    _padding = padding;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setStartRadians:(CGFloat)startRadians {
    _startRadians = startRadians;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setEndRadians:(CGFloat)endRadians {
    _endRadians = endRadians;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setFillColor:(UIColor *)color {
    _fillColor = color;
    self.shapeLayer.fillColor = color.CGColor;
}
```

Finally, we override `pointInside:withEvent:` so that hit-testing will only assign a touch to a slice view if the touch is actually inside the path of the slice.  This is critical since all of the slice views will have a frame that covers the whole screen.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return CGPathContainsPoint(self.shapeLayer.path, NULL, point, NO);
}

@end
```

Now that we have a handy `SliceView` class, we can use it to draw a pie chart with zoomable slices.  It's hard to fit two fingers into a slice on an iPhone screen, so we'll let the user tap a slice to select it, and pinch anywhere to scale the selected slice.  (This interface also makes it testable in the simulator.)

```
@implementation ViewController {
    __weak SliceView *_selectedSlice;
}
```

We'll draw unselected slices in red and the selected slice in blue.

```
+ (UIColor *)unselectedSliceFillColor {
    return UIColor.redColor;
}

+ (UIColor *)selectedSliceFillColor {
    return UIColor.blueColor;
}
```

When the user taps a slice, we'll need to change the colors of the prior selection and the new selection, and record the new selection.

```
- (IBAction)sliceWasTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapper {
    _selectedSlice.fillColor = self.class.unselectedSliceFillColor;
    _selectedSlice = (SliceView *)tapper.view;
    _selectedSlice.fillColor = self.class.selectedSliceFillColor;
}
```

When the user pinches, we adjust the transform of the selected slice, if there is one.

```
- (IBAction)pinched:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pincher {
    if (!_selectedSlice)
        return;
    CGFloat scale = pincher.scale;
    pincher.scale = 1;
    _selectedSlice.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_selectedSlice.transform, scale, scale);
}
```

Finally, we need to actually create the slice views and the gesture recognizers.  We create one tap recognizer for each slice, and one “global” pinch recognizer attached to the background view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    static int const SliceCount = 12;
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    for (int i = 0; i < SliceCount; ++i) {
        SliceView *slice = [[SliceView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        slice.startRadians = 2 * M_PI * i / SliceCount;
        slice.endRadians = 2 * M_PI * (i + 1) / SliceCount;
        slice.padding = 4;
        slice.fillColor = self.class.unselectedSliceFillColor;
        slice.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view addSubview:slice];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sliceWasTapped:)];
        [slice addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
    }

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pincher = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinched:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pincher];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image: SliceView demo screen shot]

You can download my test project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26919672/pie.zip

### UPDATE

In response to your comment asking about limiting the scale, I would suggest adding some more properties to `SliceView`:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat minScale;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat maxScale;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat scale;
```

**Important:** You will need to initialize all three properties to 1 in `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`.

Then, implement the `scale` setter to actually enforce the limits and set the scale:

```
- (void)setScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    _scale = MAX(minScale, MIN(scale, maxScale));
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(_scale, _scale);
}
```

In `pinched:`, you update the `scale` property of the view instead of setting the view's `transform` property directly:

```
- (IBAction)pinched:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pincher {
    if (!_selectedSlice)
        return;
    CGFloat scale = pincher.scale;
    pincher.scale = 1;
    _selectedSlice.scale = _selectedSlice.scale * scale;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You should write tutorials. I'm trying to set a max/min scale for the pie slices using [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079664/iphone-pixel-distortion-while-zooming-opengl-es-content-for-paint-app). I have it working I believe except for this line: `CGFloat currentScale = [[[recognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];` which is what the code uses for limiting the scale, but my currentScale doesn't change. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Where do I initialize the properties? My `initWithFrame:` returns errors and my `initWithCoder:` doesn't set the properties even though I set them to 1. Thanks for baring with me.

Comment: For whatever reason, changing `- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame` to `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One last question. If I was to create labels on each slice, would the best way to do it would be to `LabelSliceClass` and put them in the same view as the slice they sit on? Or can they just piggyback on `SliceClass` and just modify it.

Comment: I'd probably have the `SliceView` expose a `label` property of type `UILabel`.  The `SliceView` handles creating the label, adding the label to itself (the `SliceView`) as a subview, and setting the label's frame and rotation (transform) to position it properly.  Your view controller (or whatever) can set the label's text, color, font, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8046/discussion-between-tobe-sta-and-rob-mayoff)

Answer (score 1):

First, it is probably a better idea to store the slices in an array.

Second, it is also a better idea to define a class `MySliceClass` (that may inherit from UIBezierPath). This class has properties that define a slice: `startingAngle`, `endAngle`.

Now not only you improved your code, but it becomes easier to resize the slices.

You have to add a parameter `radius` to the class `MySliceClass`, and every time a slice is touched, you change its radius, and call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` so that the method `drawRect` gets called.

Finally, you should also move the initialization to the initialization method of your view because the way you do it, you create new slices every time you draw the view.

**EDIT** Here is an example implementation

```
@implementation Slice // Subclass of NSObject

@synthesize radius, startAngle, endAngle, center;

- (void)draw
{
    UIBezierPath *path = nil;
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:center];
    [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
    [path closePath];
    path.lineWidth = 1;

    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [path fill];
}

@end
```

And

```
@implementation SliceView

@synthesize slices;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        int numSlices = 12; // you can change this
        slices = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i < numSlices; i++) {
            Slice *slice = [[Slice alloc] init];
            slice.center = self.center;
            slice.radius = 100;
            slice.startAngle = (2*M_PI / numSlices) * i;
            slice.endAngle = (2*M_PI / numSlices) * (i+0.9);
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    for (Slice *slice in slices) {
    [slice draw];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGFloat d = sqrtf(powf(point.x-self.center.x, 2) + powf(point.y-self.center.y, 2));

    int index = atan2f(point.x-self.center.x, point.y-self.center.y) * self.slices.count / (2*M_PI);
    Slice *slice = [slices objectAtIndex:index];
    slice.radius = d;
}

@end
```

I didn't test this code, so there might be some errors. But you can start from this I hope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my code to reflect your suggestions. How do I target the radius of any given slice? Also, I get a CGContext error when I put the arrayOfSlices in the init method.